# Symfony Doctrine config custom types not taken into account after cache is built

Tags: symfony

Hello I have a strange behavior with Doctrine on Symfony4 (4.0.9), in the console, after the cache was generated by a first run of some command (in a dev environment) the custom types defined in config/packages/doctrine.yml are no longer taken into account.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Other informations that may be useful: I copied the app code (controllers, entities, etc.) from a Symfony2 application and imported it in a new Symfony 4 app as I'm in the process of making it compatible with Symfony 4. Also, I don't have this behavior on the web version of the app (the custom types are always recognized)

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        types:
            enumprofilecompletionstep: 'App\DBAL\EnumProfileCompletionStepPossibleValuesType'
            enumsection: 'App\DBAL\EnumSectionType'
            enumsex: 'App\DBAL\EnumSexType'
            enumstatus: 'App\DBAL\EnumStatusType'
            phone_number: 'Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Thanks for your time,
MrPOC

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I just made an edit with the doctrine config file

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue! Any ideas? @MrPOC?

Comment: @MikeyC I'd like to help you but I don't remember how I fixed it, it was too long ago 

Comment: Maybe you can try by completely removing the var/cache/<env> folder yourself